# HTML5 video background transitions only working on first loop

Tags: jquery, loops, background, html5-video, transition

I have been put in charge of a project where I need to build an application that can be displayed on huge monitors for sales people, and  it needs to look like some of those sports results on TV.

It's bascially just four divs, each with a video background and some content rotating. This works fine on the first loop, but once the four divs start again, the video background no longer works. The video "source" tag is ignored and instead the poster image shows.

I have tried several code snippets, but none of them made the video run on the second go around.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening? Is there a code snippet I missed?

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Project URL: http://illufoxdesign.com/tests/salescast/

Comment: Try finding a minimal code example that displays the problem, and embedding the code in your question. It's less useful to ask people to go look at your real site (which is a very large target).

Comment: In oder for anyone to know how the project works, they need to see the whole site, not just code snippets. This way they can test it and see the problem, then look at the code and see if anything is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, I think your problem is that you're not *playing* the video after first loop. You have the script which loops through, but no code which actually calls the `play()` method on the video.

You have the code

```
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
vid.volume = 0;
vid.play();
```

I suggest you make this into a function and call it on each loop, and play the video in focus.

If you're still unable to fix it, I'll edit this answer with a sample code.

EDIT: Modified the code. Working JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/z3Lgc75p/5/ The below JS code is the *only* thing you need within `<script></script>` tags.

```
function fadeMyContent() {
    $(".wrapper:first").fadeIn(1000, function () {
        var vid = $(this).children("#bgvid");
        vid.get(0).play();
    }).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000,

    function () {
        $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
        fadeMyContent();
    });
}
fadeMyContent();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the videos are looping when only content is changing, but once I added it to the wrapper so that I could also swap videos, not only content, the videos stopped looping. I have added "loop=true" and "video(play)" to the fade function, but that didn't make a difference. Then I added it to the other script, no difference either... I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: You have a bunch of errors in your code, which is why I asked if you could create a JSFiddle, so we can debug. - some of them are 1. videos don't have unique ids. so i don't know how the first script is even behaving 2. you're calling video(play) which I don't know even exists 3. even if it exists you're calling after `fadeMyContent()` call so it will never be reached. I've added a sample code (couldn't test anywhere) which should explicitly call the play function on a video. See if it works

Comment: Thanks, for the code. I tried it but it didn't work. I'm not a developer, but I'm usually successful tweaking other peoples codes. I have never used JSFiddle, but I can look into it and see if I can figure out how it works.

Comment: I can't really duplicate this in JSFIddle because of the large videos and so forth. The URL above shows everything, so anyone who has experience with HTML5 videos should see right away what's wrong. Unfortunately I'm new to this... :(

Comment: OK. I had some free time and went ahead and created a JSFiddle for you, since you're new to this https://jsfiddle.net/z3Lgc75p/

Comment: My code had a bug in it, which I fixed. I've edited the script. It should work now. Enjoy :) Though please note that, I haven't fixed the other bugs/issues which I pointed out. This is just an interim solution to the _specific_ problem you asked.

Comment: I doesn't seem to work in JSFiddle, but I used your modified code and tested it in the browser and it works! Only thing I noticed is that there's a slight delay before each video start (on the second go around), but hopefully nobody notices. Thanks so much for your time and patience!